# Android Studio navigate to (cmd+click) is creating a white screen

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

When I perform cmd+click sometimes to find usage of any function this white screen appears forever. I have to quit android studio every time to get rid of this. It is happening after updating to Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4.

I tried **Invalidate Cache and Restart** and clean **Re-Install** but didn't solve the problem. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: I performed a fresh install of Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3 but still facing the same issue.  Same bug for `cmd+B` alternative as well.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213632938 created issue for the same.

Comment: I finally downgraded to version 4.2.2 to fix this issue.